# Probability of Poisson event occuring at least 3 times in given interval

Tags: probability

At a parking garage, automobiles enter at a rate of $1$ car every $2$ minutes. 
I need to find the probability that the number of automobiles entering the garage during any $2$ minute period exceeds $3$.

I know $\Pr(x \gt 3)=  1-\Pr(x\le 3)$.

So, $1-\left(e^{-1} + e^{-1} + \frac{1}{2} e^{-1} + \frac{1}{6} e^{-1}\right) \dots$.

Comment: If the question is "Is this correct?" the answer is yes.

Comment: There’s something (insufficiently) fishy about that distribution ...

Comment: As part of your answer, you may be expected to explain why you used the Poisson with parameter $1$ for the number of cars entering in the $2$-minute interval.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott But the title is what kills me.

Comment: @John: That’s what the comment was about.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I guess the "kills" was too subtle an indication that I understood? :)

Answer (score -1):

About the statement

The Probability that the event exceeds 3 is **not the same** that the event happen at least 3 times.

The Probability that the event exceeds 3 is the same as the probability that the event happen at least 4 times.

Then we can perform

P(x>3) = 1 - P(x<=3)

Best Regards